# Rosserial_xbee fails to connect xbees

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My Xbee works fine with X-CTU in windows.

When I try to transfer data between XBee- end device with arduino to Xbee-coordinator connected to PC using

```
rosrun rosserial_xbee xbee_network.py /dev/ttyUSB0 1
```

I am getting following error :

```
Unable to sync with device; possible link problem or link software version mismatch such as hydro rosserial_python with groovy Arduino
```

I followed the http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_xbee/Tutorials/Example%20Network tutorial which works fine for me the first time.

But now its not working.I didn't change any version after that.

I am using ROS Hydro on Ubuntu 12.0.4

Sparkfun Xbee Kit series 1.

Can anyone please help me to solve this problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228777/rosserial_xbee-fails-to-connect-xbees/) by [RKV](https://answers.ros.org/users/26241/rkv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2016-03-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RKV](https://answers.ros.org/users/26241/rkv/) on 2016-03-13**:
The device is actually connected to "  /dev/ttyUSB0 ". Even I verified earlier.

I am tyring to narrow down the problem to know who is the root cause.

Problem is not with xbee:bcz xbee can communicate in X-CTU using windows.

Xbee configuration doesn't have any problem.

**Comment by [RKV](https://answers.ros.org/users/26241/rkv/) on 2016-03-13**:
Xbee end device RSSI is blinking means it can receive data from co-ordinator.
But CO-orninator RSSI never turns up. Means its not receiving sync from end device.SO what might be the problem in end device

**Comment by [RKV](https://answers.ros.org/users/26241/rkv/) on 2016-03-13**:
Is it the problem in software serialnode.py or hardware? Hope there wont be problem in hardware connection bcz of same hardware tested in X-CTU.So what I can do in software

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I checked with the device connection before itself as well as now with your command.

Still same problem.

I am able to check the rostopic.Which is published by Xbee as /diagnostics

### **header:
seq: 14
stamp:
secs: 1457920159
nsecs: 757045984
frame_id: ''
status:

```
level: 2
name: rosserial_python
message: no sync with device
hardware_id: ''
values: 
  - 
    key: last sync
    value: Mon Mar 14 09:49:04 2016
  - 
    key: last sync lost
    value: Mon Mar 14 09:49:19 2016**
```

Any Idea now??.. But what i think is co-ordinator able to communicate with End device with board.
The end device is not able to connect with master it seems. I dont know whats the problem.

---

Originally posted by [RKV](https://answers.ros.org/users/26241/rkv/) with karma: 26 on 2016-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RKV](https://answers.ros.org/users/26241/rkv/) on 2016-03-18**:
Problem got solved..
Try to re-configure Xbee and establish connection when its not working.